# Java wrapped images?

Tags: java, graphics

I have an image I'm drawing in java 2d but I want it to keep wrapping forever once the coordinates are outside the size of the image. The problem at the moment is that once the coordinates that I specify go outside the size of the image, it draws nothing so the image ends.

E.g an image that constantly moves horizontally and doesn't end.

```
int posx = (int) ((Player.x / 20));
int posy = (int) ((Player.y / 20));
g.drawImage(SpaceBGLayer0, 0, 0, screenwidth, screenheight, posx, posy, posx+3000, posy+3000, null, null);
```

Comment: Maybe that made sense to anyone that is not me.  If so, can they explain it?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please learn common [Java nomenclature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: I think that what he wants is some kind of rolling image. for that you need to clip (using subimage for example) your image and print once the left part on the right and then the right part on the left.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explaination. Say an image is the size of the screen, it constantly moves left, when the left of the image goes off screen i want it to appear on the right of the screen. so it seems infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap the image, you need to first test whether there's any 'overflow' (ie any parts of the screen where wrapping is required). There are 4 cases: no overflow, x-overflow, y-overflow, x- and y-overflow.

Depending on the case, you may then need to **draw additional copies** of your image displaced by 3000px in either x, y or both.

[image: Two of the four cases...]

I've assumed that your (posx,posy) point corresponds to the lower left corner of the screen, and that both screenWidth and screenHeight are less than 3000...

```
// calculate posx and posy, ensuring they lie within 0-2999:
int posx = (3000+((int)(Player.x / 20))%3000)%3000;
int posy = (3000+((int)(Player.y / 20))%3000)%3000;

// test for overflow:
boolean xOverflow = (posx+screenWidth > 3000);
boolean yOverflow = (posy+screenHeight > 3000);

// draw the image:
drawMyImage(posx,posy);
// if necessary, draw displaced copies:
if(xOverflow) drawMyImage(posx-3000,posy);
if(yOverflow) drawMyImage(posx,posy-3000);
if(xOverflow && yOverflow) drawMyImage(posx-3000,posy-3000);

...

private static void drawMyImage(int x, int y){
    int dx1 = Math.max(-x,0);
    int dy1 = Math.max(-y,0);
    int dx2 = Math.min(3000-x,screenWidth);
    int dy2 = Math.min(3000-y,screenHeight);
    int sx1 = Math.max(x,0);
    int sy1 = Math.max(y,0);
    int sx2 = Math.min(x+screenWidth,3000);
    int sy2 = Math.min(y+screenHeight,3000);
    g.drawImage(SpaceBGLayer0, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2, null, null);
}
```

I haven't tested this. You should replace all the `3000`'s with some variables, such as backgroundWidth and backgroundHeight...